# Samsung galaxy stellar root

Tags: root-access

Is there a way to root a samsung galaxy stellar (4.1.2 jb)? I've searched all over google and have come up inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you searched the wrong way because i get a lot of results: [that](http://theunlockr.com/2012/12/31/how-to-root-the-samsung-galaxy-stellar/)'s the link to theunlocker, that worked for a friend of mine. Superoneclick should work on all androids, you could get it [here](http://download.cnet.com/SuperOneClick/3000-2094_4-75447027.html).

don't worry if your rooting fails: generally there are no collateral effects

more results [here](https://www.google.it/search?q=root+a+samsung+galaxy+stellar)

Comment: I already tried all the things on google - All of them are either for the S3 or outdated (for ICS).

Comment: you can try ODIN http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2189539 (specially for samsung's phones).

Comment: Tried that, it eventually said `FAIL`.

Comment: oh... I think you are really unlucky.
even theunlocker?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53601/is-it-possible-to-root-my-phone-without-installing-a-custom-rom
that's my last comment: if it doesn't work, probabily it's your device